# c# Filter dataGridView List with a textBox

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm using this code to filter a GridView but an error appear when I start to type on that textbox.

'System.Data.EvaluateException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Cannot find column [Name].

I dont know how to repair this, can you guys help me?

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView DV = new DataView(dbdataset);
    DV.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
}
```

Comment: According to the additional information your `DataSource` doesn't have a "Name" column. Double-check your `dbdataset` for the columns it contains, what columns exist?

Comment: Yes column "Name" column is there,and I got 2 column only, "Name" and "Email".